# (VS Team Services) Building solution: The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: c#, tdd, azure-devops

We have an application which reads microsoft excel files (.xls, .xlsx, .xlsm).

It works fine:

```
Excel.Application xlApp;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
Excel.Range range;
int rCnt;
int cCnt;
int rw = 0;
int cl = 0;
xlApp = new Excel.Application();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(full_filename, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
range = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
rw = range.Rows.Count;
cl = range.Columns.Count;
for (rCnt = 1; rCnt <= rw; rCnt++)
{
    List<object> rowList = new List<object>();
    for (cCnt = 1; cCnt <= cl; cCnt++)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
xlApp.Quit();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
```

The issue is in the Visual Studio Team Services, it causes the following error during the building process:

> The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What should we setup on Visual Studio such that Team Services would be able of building ou application? Thanks

Comment: Do you have reference 'Microsoft.Office.Interop' added to your project in reference folder or lib folder?

Comment: I have a reference like this: `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting a *warning* about a missing assembly (in particular Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel) before that *error*, an assembly is not available (onto the GAC) onto the Hosted Build Agent of VSTS.

The solution is to leverage this [Nuget package Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/) and reference the assemblies provided by that Nuget package in your project.

Then the build will work eveyrwhere as long you use the Nuget Restore build task before the actual build.

Comment: I am wondering, I already had the reference to 'Microsoft.Office.Interop', why is it necessary to add in Nuget? How was that working without it?

Comment: because the reference needs to point to an **existing** file. Nuget is the standard way to assure that all the dependencies are in place (i.e existing) when compiling. And of course you should not add Nuget packages to source control (e.g. to a Git repo), they should be restored during build (either with VS, either with VSTS on a build agent).