# Error on Azure pipeline 'The type or namespace name 'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft''?

Tags: c#, azure

I am getting the following error on Azure pipeline:

```
GIFValWebApp\Services\ExcelReportHandler.cs(11,25): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name
'Office' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

I am using Microsoft.Office.Excel.Interop on one of the projects of the solution and it is working fine, however, Azure fails to find the reference.

Thanks!

Comment: You need also to add a reference to the Microsoft Office 12.0 Object Library, for the base support for office interop.

Comment: Include the namspace in the .cs file. 
**using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;**

Comment: I have done repro. Please check the [Image1](https://i.imgur.com/H52b9yy.png)  and [Image2](https://i.imgur.com/aPPgRvl.png)

Comment: Include Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel  from the Nuget Package Manager and include that namespace in the using in ExcelReportHandler.cs

Comment: Pleasec refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44140687/vs-team-services-building-solution-the-type-or-namespace-name-office-does-n) once